# VSCode add dynamic environment variables into Launch.json

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Currently I have a configuration option like so in my `launch.json`

```
{
  "name": "Python: UK Tests",
  ... 
  "env": {
    "DB_CONNECTION_STRING": "couchbase://172.20.0.2/csp-aaa-api"
  }
}
```

The DB I need to connect runs in a docker container, and the "Debug" job runs on the host machine. So I have to get the IP of the Docker container from the host, using a `docker inspect` and then adjust my `launch.json` file manually. Is there any way I can dynamically set this without having to manually edit it.

Thanks

Comment: I know you can use an .env file which is something I would rather not use. Did you find a way to pass the context env variables to the launch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should be possible by using an `.env` file;

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: UK Tests",
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
        }
    ]
}
```

Where the .env file would look like: `DB_CONNECTION_STRING="couchbase://172.20.0.2/csp-aaa-api"`